# Spyder Python 3.7: An error occurred while starting the kernel -

Tags: python

`Windows 10`

I am getting the following error when i start Spyder. It was working perfectly for many months and all of a sudden started giving the error. Tried a couple of suggestions from Internet but some how nothing is working.Any help/suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\bahadurr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\bahadurr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\bahadurr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 11, in 
start.main()
File "C:\Users\bahadurr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 287, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "C:\Users\bahadurr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "C:\Users\bahadurr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 895, in 
from spyder_kernels.py3compat import TimeoutError, PY2, _print, encode
ImportError: cannot import name 'TimeoutError' from 'spyder_kernels.py3compat' (C:\Users\bahadurr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py)
```

Comment: What things did you try? Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: I have tries "Reset Spyder Settings Anaconds 3", from Tools > Reset Spyder to Factory Defaults",

Comment: I did not try some suggestions e.g.uninstall and reinstall as Spyder was working perfectly for months. In between two runs it started giving the error. There was no update to the system in span of 5 minutes